# Dynamic sql query(string template)

Tags: python, sqlite

Let's say I have a working function that prints first record from  DataBase:

```
class DataBase:
    def db_firstrecord(self):

        self.execute("SELECT * FROM Flat")
        row = self.fetchall()
        row = row[0]
        print(row)

def main():
    DB.DataBase.db_firstrecord(cur)
```

I have recently found that there are several ways of making dynamic sql queries(sql string templates). And I want to use my initial function with different table names. How can I implement it in clean and safety manner ?

I want something like this:

```
class DataBase:
    def db_firstrecord(self,`Table_name`):

        self.execute("SELECT * FROM `Table_name`")
        row = self.fetchall()
        row = row[0]
        print(row)

def main():
    DB.DataBase.db_firstrecord(cur,`Table_name`)
```

Comment: Which library are you using to connect to the database? It likely provides some way to sanitize the inputs. Other than that, you'd just have to change the function definition of `db_firstrecord` to accept a single parameter like `table_name`. Also consider that the library you use may already provide a convenience method that returns the first row of a table.

Comment: @MikhailGolubitsky  Returning the first row need not be just a library function, it is usually built in to any SQL implementation.  For sqlite you just append `LIMIT 1` to end of the select query.

Comment: Parameterized queries are used to "sanitize" inputs into a query and make the query "dynamic", but they are only for data values, not database schema object names (i.e. tables, columns, etc.).  You could just use string concatenation and for literal values entered in code that could be sufficient, but be careful to avoid SQL injection if you are accepting user input for building such dynamic queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a whitelist of valid table names.

```
class Database:
    table_names = {'table1', 'table2', ...}

    def db_firstrecord(self, table_name):
        if table_name not in table_names:
            raise ValueError

        self.execute(f"SELECT * FROM `{table_name}` LIMIT 1")
        row = self.fetch()
        return row
```

Note that you can't put backticks in around the Python variable in the parameter list. It needs to be in the SQL string.

And there's no reason to fetch all rows if you just want the first. Tell the query to return only one row, and just use `fetch()` rather than `fetchall()`.